# MapServer : background buffer around labels ( GEOMTRANSFORM 'labelpoly' )

Tags: labeling, buffer, mapserver, background

I'm struggling on MapServer trying to create better and smoother background buffer around labels using GEOMTRANSFORM 'labelpoly' function documented here https://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapfile/geomtransform.html#labelpnt-and-labelpoly

[image: Actual labelling state]

```
  CLASS
    NAME "Chantiers forestiers"
    TEXT "[type_travaux]$[situation]$ Du [date_debut] $ Au [date_fin]"
    STYLE
      COLOR 0 255 0
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END
    LABEL
      MAXSCALEDENOM 20000
      FONT arial
      TYPE truetype
      SIZE 10
      COLOR 0 0 0
      POSITION AUTO
      WRAP "$"
      STYLE
        OPACITY 80
        GEOMTRANSFORM 'labelpoly'
        COLOR 255 255 255
        OFFSET 2 2
      END
    END
```

Any idea on how we could achieve this? (trying to achieve it on MapServer)

Minimal would be larger than 1px rectangle buffer (eg 5px)

[image: Better Labelling rectangle]

Better would be rounded rectangle buffer which I was not able to achieve on QGIS yet

[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of the better and smoother background from QGIS?

Comment: Not so easy to achieve on QGIS as I thought, we miss maybe some rounded rectangle buffer option or to be able to use the geometry generator on the label extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear that fine tuning the labelpoly option is not possible without touching the source code.

- The size of the rectangle is fixed to 1 pixel padding
  https://mapserver.org/mapfile/label.html?#label-style

> labelpoly generates the bounding rectangle for the text, with 1 pixel
> of padding added in all directions.

- Labelpoly cannot be used in chained transformations because they are supported only at LAYER and CLASS STYLE level https://mapserver.org/mapfile/geomtransform.html#expressions-and-advanced-transformations-layer-and-class-style

I believe that the desired result could be achieved if it was possible to apply a buffer to labelpoly

```
GEOMTRANSFORM (buffer([labelpoly], 5))
```

It is already possible to color the boundary of the labelpoly with OUTLINECOLOR but for my mind it does not make the result much nicer. I suggest to write mail to mapserver-users mailing list and introduce your problem. A minimal improvement might be to change the default padding of labelpoly into 3 or 5 pixels. With 1 pixel the box is rather cramped.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @user30184 it is possible to add some OUTLINECOLOR AND WIDTH to the generated labelpoly

[image: Smoothed polygons]

```
  CLASS
    NAME "Chantiers forestiers"
    TEXT "[type_travaux]$[situation]$ Du [date_debut] $ Au [date_fin]"
    STYLE
      COLOR 0 255 0
      OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
    END
    LABEL
      MAXSCALEDENOM 20000
      FONT arial
      TYPE truetype
      SIZE 10
      COLOR 0 0 0
      POSITION AUTO
      WRAP "$"
      STYLE
        OPACITY 80
        GEOMTRANSFORM 'labelpoly'
        COLOR 255 255 255
        OFFSET 2 2
        OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
        WIDTH 15.0
      END
    END
  END
```

This is not perfect on transparent shapes (since there is an overlap between border and fill) but is as expected smoothed and

[image: Smoothed]